# basic firebase + dialogflow - repeated agent add dialogflow

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dialogflow-es

really appreciate the helps

I have been following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xWpHVbMnBXI&ab_channel=PeterFessel) with this [code](https://www.peterfessel.com/2018/07/google-dialogflow-chatbot-realtime-database-tutorial-read-write/).

My code looks like this

```
function angerEmotionCapture(agent) {
    const angryTo = agent.parameters.angryDirectedTo;
    return admin.database().ref('directedTo').transaction((directedTo)=>{
      let target = directedTo;
      agent.add(`previous entry was ${target}`);
      target = angryTo;
      agent.add(`new entry is ${target}`);
      return directedTo;
    });
  }
```

The purpose of this is to capture a conversation topic and store it in the database.
I'm planning to use it for multiple purposes that's why I don't use context.
This code is only the first step to see if I can capture it properly.

When doing this, the agent response always look like this

```
previous entry was null
new entry is boss
previous entry was friends
new entry is boss
```

Here "friends" and "boss" are expected. However, the first repetition is not expected and it always gives null. Despite of that, this correctly update the database

I want to understand why is there a repetition here
Thanks, really appreciate the time

Comment: just put an if statement (if directedTo and angryTo are not null then add them to the agent). I do not see the point of assigning them to variable 'target'.

Comment: @Gray_Rhino that works, thanks! Do you mind explaining why it will be repeated without !== null ?